# langage plpython3u not allowed

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpython

I am working on debian jessie

I have installed the language :

```
aptitude install postgresql-plpython3
```

then :

```
% createlang plpython3u template1
```

then :

```
% psql
postgres=# CREATE LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

I have tried this function :

```
Create or replace function test() returns void as $$
print('Bonjour le monde')
$$ language plpython3u;
```

I have tried to force the db :

```
createlang plpython3u db_test
```

And i get the message, it is already installed, so I don't know what to do more ??

Comment: Show the *exact error messages* please.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `print`. Use sys.stderr instead the output will be logged in /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-X.X-main.log (replace X.X by your postgresql version)

```
Create or replace function test(text) returns void as $$
import sys
name = args[0]
sys.stderr.write('Bonjour {}\n'.format(name))
$$ language plpython3u;
select test('sardon');
```